# How to find out the angle of this projection plane?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve a small projection problem. I need to find out the angle of my projection plane (the upper red line in the picture).

The top edge of the square should result in x distance on the projection plane, and the left edge should result in 2x. How do I find the angle a?

[image: Projection]

So far, I've come up with this solution, but I am in no way certain if it's the right answer:

- x is the shorter edge of a right triangle, 2x is the longer edge, and hypotenuse equals 1
- Therefore

  - $x^2 + 2x^2 = 1^2$
  - $3x^2 = 1$
  - $x^2 = 1/3$
  - $x = sqrt(1/3)$

Now, I'm not quite sure on this, but the angle would be just $acos(sqrt(1/3))$, or about 54.74 degrees. Is this even remotely close?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you mean by those "distances": clearly, the upper left corner of the square is much close to what you call "projection plane" (projection...of **what** ?) than the upper right one, so *what exactly* is that "distance"?

Comment: Umm, it's hard to explain, but imagine the plane is an orthographic projection plane of a cube, and the problem is just the "side view", or just two dimensions of a three-dimensional problem. Apologies if I don't make any sense; I'm by no means a mathematician.

Comment: I guess that "orthographic" was meant to be "orthogonal", otherwise this question belongs more to grammar than to mathematics...:), and perhaps you mean "the projection" of the square (a two dimensional one)  on a plane...?

Comment: Yes, orthogonal! And yes, a square projected on a plane (or, err, a line?)

Comment: A line is just fine...yet the problem of the "distance" remains: for example, is $\;x\;$ the distance from the upper left vertex, the upper right one or the middle of the upper side, to that line (plane) on the left? Without knowing this it is going to be tough to know what to do, I'm afraid...but perhaps someone else can make sense of this.

Comment: You should have $(2x)^2$ not $2x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\sin\alpha=2x$ and $\cos\alpha=x$ so $\tan\alpha=2$